# How do I prevent sudden line jump when scrolling through file with linebreaks?

Tags: scrolling

I'm using vim to read through a script. I want to prevent sudden, jarring transitions from when scrolling down after reaching the bottom of the screen. I want to vim to scroll just one linebreak at a time. I'm not sure this is even possible.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried scrolling with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>y</kbd> (up) and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd> (down) instead?  You may want to do `:set display+=lastline` too.

Other than that you're not going to be able to do what you want, because Vim always wants the entire line the cursor is on to be fully displayed.

Comment: Not true: you can `:set nowrap`

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Good point, and something I should have thought of.